# Fill a Table with the values of my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I think this should be an easy question but I am dont know to how to do it haha.

I have a df (3x3) and a table in powerpoint (also 3x3). Now I would like to fill my table with the values of the dataframe.

```
Here is my code I tried:
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    a = a + 1
    b = b + 1
    cell = table.cell(0, 0)
    cell.text
    cell.text = df.value
```

But this is not working

Comment: what's `table` type? `type(table)` ?

Comment: Its a table = graphic_frame.table in powerpoint